# Is there such a scheduler and is it feasible?

Tags: scheduling, posix

I read about a scheduling algorithm called EDD which always works on the next deadline and that is feasible. Would it also be feasible to within each time windows or slice, work on all processor or all of a set of processor so that it is guaranteed that all of the processos have gotten some work within some certain time winfowd? And would that be a feasible scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it would not be feasible, although I can't say if it exists on any *nix OS (it might on the more specialized ones such as [QNX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QNX), but I have my doubts about more general-purpose systems like OS X, FreeBSD or Linux). The [Wikipedia article that mentions Earliest Due Date scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_due_date#Heuristics) doesn't cite any sources, but the [article on real-time operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system#Algorithms) specifically talks about [Earliest Deadline First scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling) which sounds very similar.

The EDF article talks specifically about "whenever a scheduling event occurs". Such an event (for example: a new process, or a process finishing) isn't bound to any particular processor, and it would be a particularly dumb scheduler implementation that doesn't utilize the system's available computational resources.

A proper RTOS might have trouble with synchronizing process and thread mutexes and other interlocks, but that would be a problem regardless of the scheduling algorithm in use, particularly if the system has more than one execution unit (CPU core).